# Are there important differences to know about between boost::function and std::tr1::function

Tags: c++, boost, tr1, boost-function

I use boost a lot in my code but have so far refrained from using `std::tr1`. Now I need a more sophisticated function pointer, like those two can provide. Unfortunately C+11 is not an option yet. I read that `boost::function` can be tricky with certain compilers e.g. (Visual Studio before 7.1 needs a special [portable syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html)) but have not found any information on `std::tr1::function` regarding this subject. Are there any important differences concerning memory usage, speed and compatibility between the two ?

Edit: I am currently using gcc 4.7 but the code should also compile on Visual Studio and preferably also slightly more dated versions like 2005

Comment: Differences regarding memory usage and speed are certainly implementation dependent, so answering that without knowing your platform/compiler is kind of hard. Besides both have a non trivial overhead, so if the performance/memory are really tight you might not want to use either, otherwise I doubt the differences will be big enough to matter. And what exactly do you mean with compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you read? What do you mean by tricky? Are you referring to some ancient compilers only supporting the `boost::function1<void, int>` form rather than `boost::function<void(int)>` form?

`std::tr1::function` should be provided *by* your compiler, so if your compiler provides it at all then it should work perfectly, and not be "tricky" (whatever you mean by that.)

Asking if there are differences between Boost's specific implementation and an interface specification, which is not an implementation, doesn't make sense.  One implementation could be similar to Boost's and have no substantial differences and another implementation could be completely different. GCC's `std::tr1::function` was contributed by the author of Boost.Function, so it's *very* similar.

Comment: Many thanks, you make good guesses on inaccurate questions. You are quite right about the difference between interface and implementation. Boost is boost but tr1.... Should have given it a second thought

Comment: In my experience `boost`, `tr1` and `cxx11` function objects are rather easy to exchange. All of them provide compatibility with the deprecated `unary/binary_function` templates. If you are aiming for pre VS2005, `boost::function` is the way to go.

Comment: @pmr makes a very good point, I was a bit pedantic - `tr1::function` was based on `boost::function` so they are conceptually very similar, and in practice you probably won't notice differences between most TR1 implementations and Boost.Function.